# CSS transform skew for menu

Tags: css, menu, html-lists, transform, skew

I'm trying to create a skewed menu in a header with drop downs. It seems that the skew works properly on the main nav items but the dropdown doesn't work. When I remove the skew, the dropdown works.

Here's my code:

```
#header .menu > li {
    background-color: #959595 !important;
    -ms-transform: skew(20deg);
    -webkit-transform: skew(20deg);
    -moz-transform: skew(20deg);
    -o-transform: skew(20deg);
    transform: skew(20deg);
    z-index: 99 !important;
}

#header ul.menu li:hover>ul,
#header ul.menu li.sfHover ul,
#header .menu li:hover>ul,
#header .menu li.sfHover ul {
    z-index: 999 !important;
    position: absolute;
    left: auto;
}

#header .menu li a.sf-with-ul {
    padding-right: 25px;
}
```

Also, here's a link to the current website:

[wordpress site](http://www.360industrialmovers.com/wordpress)

Please help...

Answer (score 0):

Try applying your skew to the 'a' tag instead of the 'li' tag. Your first level navigation will be skew, but not your second level and they will be visible when you hover over it.

```css
li a {
  -ms-transform: skew(20deg);
  -webkit-transform: skew(20deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(20deg);
  -o-transform: skew(20deg);
  transform: skew(20deg);
  background-color: #959595 !important;
}
```

```html
<li id="menu-item-56" class="skewed-menu-item menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-56">
  <a href="http://360industrialmovers.com/wordpress/about/" class="sf-with-ul">About<span class="sf-sub-indicator"> »</span></a>
  <ul class="sub-menu" style="display: none;">
    <li id="menu-item-339" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-339"><a href="http://360industrialmovers.com/wordpress/about/360-client-guarantee/">360 Client Guarantee</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```